# Python-3 Pandas: Using whitespace as a delimiter gives error due to an extra white space in the one of the rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read the below data frame from a text file, using whitespace as a delimiter in columns:

```
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
GigabitEthernet1       10.10.20.48     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet2       unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet3       unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
```

But there is a extra white space in the rows due to which I am getting error:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 3, saw 7
```

The words "administratively down" in the column status need to be considered as a single word with a space in between both the words "adminstratively" and "down", however I am getting the error when reading this data in pandas

Python code which I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('D:\\python\\python-cisco-status.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row[4] == 'administratively down' or row[4] == 'down':
        print(f"Interface {row[0]} is down in ")
```

I am looking to read the above mentioned data in pandas, so I can read row by row and check if any interface is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of your file is not `csv`/`dsv`, you should use appropriate pandas function - `pandas.read_fwf()` - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, when I use pandas.read_fwf() function to read, it is adding a new unnamed column and reading 5 columns as 6 columns. For example, the string "down" in the "administratively down" is considered as a new column, however my requirement is that "administratively down"  should be read as in the same column "status" instead of a new one.

Comment: @aman `data = pd.read_fwf(*filename*, widths=[23, 16, 3, 7, 22, 8])`

Comment: Thank you for your help, script is now working as expected, could you also help me if there is a way that I can read the output from a terminal into pandas dataframe, instead of writing the output from terminal to file and then from file I am reading this output. For example data = pd.read_fwf("output from a terminal after running a command" instead of "filename").

Comment: @aman Please read the reference I provided in the answer, it says `filepath_or_buffer` - `object with a read() method`. Exact implementation depends on the data source. Is `output from terminal` returned by some command/code? Then write the data to the buffer `io.StringIO()` and load with pandas.

Comment: Thank you for your help